# randomforest Regressor with all independent variable as categorical

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression, data-science, random-forest

I am stuck in the process of building a model.Basically I have 10 parameters all of which are categorical variables, Even the categories have a large number of unique values (one category has 1335 unique values of 300 000 records), and the y value which is to be predicted is the number of days (Numerical). I am using randomforestregressor and getting an accuracy of around 55-60%. I am not sure if this is the max limit or I really need to change the algorithm itself. I am flexible with any kind of solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Having up to 1335 categories for a categorical dimension might cause a random forest regressor (or classifier) some headache depending on how categorical dimensions are handled internally, and things will also depend on the distribution frequencies of the categories. What library are you using for the random forest regression?

Have you tried converting the categorical dimensions into unique integer IDs and interpreting this representation as a real number dimension? I've made the experience that this can raise the variable importance of many a type of categorical dimensions. (At times the inherent/initial ordering of the categories can provide useful grouping/partitioning information).
You can even shuffle your dimensions a few times and use these as input dimensions. I'll try to explain with an example:

You have a categorical dimension x1 with categories [c11,c12,...,c1n]
We easily map these categories to numerical values by saying x1 has a value of 1 if it's the category is c11, or a value of 2 if it's category, or a value or i for category c1i etc.
Use this new **non-categorical** dimension as an input dimension for training (you will have to change your input to the regressor accordingly later on).
You can go further than this. Shuffle the order (randomly) of your categories of x1 so you get a random order, for example [c13,c19,c1n,c1i,...,c12]. Do the same thing as above and you have another new **non-categorical** input dimension (Consider that you'll have to remember the shuffling order for the sake of regression later on).
I'm curious if adding a few (anywhere between 1 to 100, or whatever number you choose) dimensions like this can improve your performance.
Please, see how performance changes for different numbers of such dimensions. (But be aware that more such dimensions will cost you in preprocessing time at regression)

The statement in the codeblock below would require combining multiple categorical dimensions at once. Consider it only for inspiration.

```
Another idea would be to check if some form of linear classifier with the hot-encodings for each individual category for multiple categorical dimensions might be able improve things (This can help you find useful orderings more quickly than the approach above).
```

Comment: Thank you for the response,I am using sklean's ensemble randomforestregressor, all the values are in ids(ex:1,2,134 etc),If i understand correctly you are suggesting me to perform one-hot encoding, but my fear is that the horizontal length of dataset would be too large considering even the other parameters which are also categorical,

Comment: Considering sklearn's documentation ([RFC Doc)]([example](http://example.com "merely an example")) it seems like a standard implementation of the RF algorithm without any tweaks, so the one-hot encoding should be done in the Random Forest training anyway. I see the explanation is trickier than I thought. I'll edit and add some example to my previous answer to highlight the ideas .

Answer (score -1):

I am sure you need to more processing on your data.
having 1335 unique values on one variable is something bizarre.
please, if the data is public share it with me, I want to take a look.